# Formal Definition of the Product of Two Sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

I am taking a course in Algebraic Structures, and the notion of *product of sets* (*a.k.a.* Caratesian Product) came in. We were given a definition that made me feel I didn't understand it. They gave the following definition:

Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a non-empty family of sets. That's to say, $I$ is a non-empty set and for each $i ∈ I$ we consider a set $A_i$. A product (also called the Cartesian product) of the family $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a set $A$ and an family $\{π_i : A \to A_i\}_{i\in I}$, called the projections of the product $A$ in its factors $A_i$, such that for every set $B$ and all every $\{\psi_i : B \to Ai\}_{i\in I}$ of applications, there is a single application  $\psi : B \to A$ such that all of the following diagrams are commutative:
[image]

I don't see how this definition corresponds to the usual and simple way of thinking about the Cartesian product. Can someone shade a bit of light on this?

Comment: Start from the def of [Cartesian product of a family of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995119/cartesian-product-using-family-of-sets). The key-point is that the "usual" $\times$ definition is applicable only to a finite number of sets.

Comment: The general def of the product of family $\{ A_i \}_{i \in I}$ is $A = \{ f_i : I \to \bigcup A_i \mid f(i) \in A_i \}$. This def induces in a natural way the "projection functions" $\psi_i : A \to A_i$ that associate to the uple the $i$-th element.

Comment: Misprint: read $\pi_i$ in place of $\psi_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, say, $I=\{1,2,3\}$, then you have $3$ sets: $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$. Let $\pi_1\colon(A_1\times A_2\times A_3)\longrightarrow A_1$ be the map defined by $\pi_1(a_1,a_2,a_3)=a_1$ and defined $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$ in a similar way.

Now, suppose that $B$ is a set and that you have $3$ maps $\psi_1\colon B\longrightarrow A_1$, $\psi_2\colon B\longrightarrow A_2$, and $\psi_3\colon B\longrightarrow A_3$. Then you can define $\psi\colon B\longrightarrow A_1\times A_2\times A_3$ by $\psi(b)=\bigl(\psi_1(b),\psi_2(b),\psi_3(b)\bigr)$ and, for each $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, you have $\pi_1\circ\psi=\psi_i$. What this shows is the the usual Cartesian product $A_1\times A_2\times A_3$ is a Cartesian product in the sense of the definition that you gave.

Comment: Thank you José Carlos Santos and Mauro ALLEGRANZA for your answers and comments, they have solve my question!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.