# On the definition of Cartesian product.

Tags: functions, set-theory

Let $(a_1,a_2..a_n)$ denote a n-tuple. Consider the following collection of functions,
$$\{f:\{1,2....n\}\rightarrow \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_{k} \mid f(u)\in A_u                      \forall u\in\{1,2....n\}\}$$
It's obvious that we may have the same elements but one is a tuple and other is a set. And hence they aren't equal. Indeed we have that,
$$(a_1,a_2....a_n)=(f(1)....f(n))$$
If we set $f(k)=a_k$ for $k\in\{1,2..n\}$ and $a_k\in A_k$

But in the definition of Cartesian product something contradictory is happening (According to me),

Let,
$X$ be some non empty set. For each $x\in X$ define $A_x$ to be a non empty set. Then let's denote $\prod_{x\in X} A_x$ as the Cartesian product of all such $A_x$. Then every element of it is collection of
$$f:X\rightarrow \bigcup_{x\in X}A_x \hspace{1.5mm}\mid f(k)\in A_k \forall k\in \{1,2...n\}$$

Question,

1. If the above mentioned collection of functions is not a ordered pair but a set which actually consists of same elements of that ordered pair, then why is this considered to be an ordered pair?

I saw the following definition in the page  13 of [this](https://auislandora.wrlc.org/islandora/object/thesesdissertations%3A445/datastream/PDF/view) article

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995119/cartesian-product-using-family-of-sets) question on MSE actually contained my question but I want more satisfying answer(in a sense of condition I took)

Comment: Well, how to define $n$-tuples (of a set $A$)? It's generally accepted to define them exactly as functions $\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to A$. Then, a straightforward generalization is to regard a function $X\to A$ as an '$X$-tuple' of $A$.