# What is a function at all?

Tags: functions, set-theory

Let $$f:\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow \{1,4,9\}$$
$$f(x)=x^{2}$$
Then I can represent it as ordered pairs as follows
$$f=\{(1,1),(2,4),(3,9)\}$$
Let me know if I am going right.
My question is, can the function also be represented as ordered pairs consisting of all $y$-coordinates i.e is
$$f=\langle 1,4,9\rangle$$

I got this question due to answer given to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995119/cartesian-product-using-family-of-sets) question. He gives an example at last, saying that the ordered pair $\langle 1,3 \rangle$ can be represented by the function $f:\{1,2\}\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$ and $1\rightarrow 1$ and $2 \rightarrow 3$

Now I am having a hard time understanding all these stuff. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We can view an ordered pair $(a,b)$ as a function $f$ on $\{1,2\}$ with $f(1)=a$ and $f(2)=b$. Likewise, as in your example, we can view a point like $(1,4,9)$ as a function on $\{1,2,3\}$ defined just as you say. This allows us to view n-dimensional euclidean space as the set of functions on $\{1,2,...,n\}$.

Comment: Continuing on the comment of @JohnDouma the set $A×B$ can be looked at as the set of functions $f:\{1,2\}\to A\cup B$ that satisfy $f(1)\in A$ and $f(2)\to B$. But we might as well interpret $AxB$ as the set of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ (and usually we do).

Comment: I can write down *anything* to represent a function so long as I as explain it.  I can write a function $f:\{1,...,10\}\to \{1,2,3,5\}$ via $f(1)=1;f(2)=3;f(3)=2;f(4)=3;f(5)=5;f(6)=3;f(7)=3;f(8)=3;f(9)=3;f(10)=5$ by writing the sentence "A rat in the house may eat the ice cream". Why is that a function? Because the number of each word is mapped to the letters of the word.  So I can write your function as "I like mushrooms". (because $1\to 1;2\to 4;3\to 9$). But if I do this I have to *explain* what I doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a function you have domain set $\{1,2,3\}$ which is a set of all possible things that get maps.  And you have a codomain $\{1,4,9\}$ which is the set of all the possible things that might get mapped to.

But a function has to *be* the mapping and *how* the items must exist. One way or another there is the concept that $1$ is mapped to $1$, and the $2$ is mapped to $4$.  And the $3$ is mapped to $9$.  Any mechanism that does this will be okay.

The conventional way is to have a set of ordered pairs, $(\text{the thing being mapped},\text{the thing being mapped to})$ so you function can be written as $\{(1,1),(2,4),(3,9)\}$.

(Note: when you said "Let
f:{1,2,3}→{1,4,9}
Then I can represent it as ordered pairs as follows..." you never stated what the actually mapping *is*.  We know that $1,2$ and $3$ each get mapped to *one of* $1,4,9$ but we have no idea which.)

Now although conventionally we can represent a mapping of $1\mapsto 1; 2\mapsto 4;3\mapsto 9$ as  $\{(\text{the thing being mapped},\text{the thing being mapped to})\}$ of for you function $\{(1,1),(2,4),(3,9)\}$, but that is not the only *possible* way.

We could represent it as pair of $n$-tuples (assuming the domain is finite or even countable) but letting one $n$-tuple be $\langle\text{first thing being mapped},\text{second thing being mapped}.....\rangle$ and the other $n$-tuple being $\langle\text{what the first thing is being mapped to},\text{what the second thing is being mapped to}....\rangle$

For your function that is $\langle 1,2,3\rangle \to \langle 1,4,9\rangle$.

These are just notations.  They express the same thing.

Comment: So @fleablood, according to you is it valid also to write   this function as $\langle 1,4,9 \rangle$. And it's not at all an abuse of notation

Comment: @Rahul You can do that but only if you have made clear ahead that the domain corresponds with ordered triple $\langle 1,2,3\rangle$. Presentation of a function requires a presentation of its domain.

Comment: @drhab, kindly have a look at my edit.

Comment: Well...no... If you write $\langle 1,4,9\rangle$ by itself I don't know what you mean.  Even if I knew it was a function  I don't know if $\langle 1,4,9 \rangle$ are the things that are being mapped from (to what) or if they are the things being mapped to (from what)... also no matter *what* notation you use I have to know what those black and what markings on my computer screen are supposed to me and in what context.  If I say a piece of paper with $\langle 1,4,9 \rangle$ on it I'd have no idea what it was supposed to mean.

Comment: @fleablood, If so then why any element from my n-tuple is defined as a function from index set to union of $A_{k}$ such that it contains one element of my $A_{k}$?

Comment: Because he *said* that's what it was.  He said:  "I am writing a function with domain of $\{1,2,3,.....,k\}$ and I am going to represent it by writing an ordered list of numbers where the first number is $f(1)$ the second number is $f(2)$ and the $k$th number is $f(k)$.  So that means if I write $\langle 1,4,9\rangle$ I am using that as a code I just made up and just explained to you to mean the function of $1\to1;2\to4;3\to9$"... I could say "I'm writing the function as a bunch of # and !.  we can't the number of #s separated by !s so I write your function as #!####!#########"

Comment: None of this is talking about what a function *is* (which is a mapping of elements of a domain set to elements of a codomain set so that each distinct element of the domain set is paired to exactly one element of the codomain set).  These are just talking about how we can *represent* the function.  He just came up with a convenient shorthand.  That is all.

Comment: Actually I do not see anywhere where the poster wrote a function as an $n$-tuple.  I only see the standard definition as a set of ordered pairs.  Some people (such as me) will write an ordered pair using parenthesis (so the pair where the first element is 2 and the second if 4 is written as $(2,4)$) while other people (such as that poster) write them with angle brackets (so $\langle 2,4\rangle$).  In either case the *conventional* way to write your function is $\{(1,1),(2,4)(3,9)\}$ (or as $\{\langle1,1\rangle\langle2,4\rangle\langle3,9\rangle\}$).

Answer (score 0):

So typically we define a function as follows:

Let $A,B$ be sets. A function is some $f \subseteq A \times B$ such that for each $a \in A$, there is a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$.

Now we write $f(a)$ to mean the unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$.

Now, this coincides with one of your representations, where you've written out all the ordered pairs, hence a subset of $A \times B$.

But there are some other ways you can think of it, as long as its consistent with the original definition. If your domain set $A$ is finite (say $A = \{a_1, ..., a_n\}$) or at least countable, then representing a function $f$ as
$$f = \langle f(a_1), ..., f(a_n) \rangle $$
seems totally fine to me, but I don't think its super conventional (at least not outside of set theory). The only issue with this is that it doesn't reference the domain, so you need to be careful.